# Ошибка в роутинге

Tags: php

Хотел сделать роутинг на чистом php, но потом меня черт дернул установить symfony/router и теперь я чувствую себя идиотои. У меня проблема с подключением классов, делал по инструкции и получил:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AppController' not found in /home/vagrant/html/phb/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 151
```

Вот что впилил:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel;
use App\Http\Controller\AppController;

$dotenv = new Dotenv();
$dotenv->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$routes = new RouteCollection();
$routes->add('main', new Route('/',
        array(
            '_controller' => 'AppController::index',
        )
    )
);


$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
$resolver = new HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver();

try {
    $request->attributes->add($matcher->match($request->getPathInfo()));
    $controller = $resolver->getController($request);
    $arguments = $resolver->getArguments($request, $controller);
    $response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
    $response = new Response('Not found', 404);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response = new Response('Error occurred', 500);
}

$response->send();
```

Где глупость я сделал?

Comment: Надо указать полное название класса?

Comment: @u_mulder дак я же сделал use App\Http... или где

Comment: В _controller когда передаете.

Comment: @u_mulder неа, там бестолку, точно такая же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```php
$routes->add('main', new Route('/',
        array(
            '_controller' => 'App\Http\Controller\AppController::index',
        )
    )
);
```

Почему так? Потому что вы передаете строкой в объект `Route`, а там будет подключаться класс `AppController`, и там нет объявленного `use App\Http\Controller\AppController`.

Так же с **php 5.3.0** вы можете сделать вот так, правда у вас action `index` вряд ли отработает(зависит от класса `Route`):

```php
$routes->add('main', new Route('/',
        array(
            '_controller' => AppController::class,
        )
    )
);
```

Вообщем вся фича в том, что вы передаете полный namespace, т.к. класс там будет вызываться *анонимно*. А константа `AppController::class` возвращает полное имя класса, т.е. если вы пропишите сейчас в вашем файле:

```php
echo AppController::class;  // output: 'App\Http\Controller\AppController'
```

---

Что у вас написано в файле:

```
use App\Http\Controller\AppController;
```

И что написано в `AppController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Обратите внимание на слово Controller(**s**), вы определитесь, ставить вам букву или нет )

Еще замечание, у вас в `composer.json` прописано:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app"
    }
}
```

А надо:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помогает полный путь

Comment: Добавьте "верхушку" класса `AppController` в вопрос, все что идет до `class AppController`

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: @PaulWall, Правил ответ, смотрите в конце

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю и попробую у себя развернуть, уже просто вижу что ошибочка может быть в `composer.json`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98351/discussion-between-mully-and-paul-wall).